# How do I take the text from a textbox and make it into a usable file path in C#?

Tags: c#

Here's my working code:

```
string outputpath = @"C:\today\abc.txt";
var outputdata = query.ToList();
File.AppendAllLines(outputpath, outputdata);
```

Now instead of defining "outputpath" in the code, I want to set it equal to the contents of a textbox.

```
string outputpath = textBox1.Text;
```

This doesn't compile.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The error I get is "Error 1, A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.textBox1'.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "This doesn't compile" doesn't give us much information. What's the error? Where are you doing this? Is `textBox1` actually declared in the class where you're trying to do this?

Comment: The error has to be somewhere else. textBox1.Text is correct.

Comment: @VaibhavDesai: not if textBox1 isn't declared, as Jon Skeet points out, or if it isn't a TextBox object.

Comment: Explain what is the type of `query`

Comment: I am not sure how you are getting the error, but instead of TextBox consider using FileDialogs probably [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)

Comment: @AdamV: Agreed. But that would be too obvious to track. Also, the name screams that it is a textbox

Comment: If outputpath is a field, you must initialize it after textBox1 is initialized. Try declaring string outputpath; and then initalize outputpath = textbox1.Text; somewhere else, such as your constructor.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I'm not sure.  I just threw a textBox onto my form.  But there's no mention of textBox anywhere in my code.  This would be the first and only mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to initalize a field based on the value of a non-static object. You can't do that, since the object doesn't exist during initialization.

This is no good:

```
public class Form
{
    TextBox textBox1;
    string outputPath = textbox1.Text;
}
```

This should work, although the value will probably be an empty string:

```
public class Form
{
    TextBox textBox1;
    string outputPath;

    public Form()
    {
        outputPath = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

But what you probably want is to hook a button's OnClick event, or something similar, to assign the textBox1.Text value to outputpath.

Comment: Thanks Michael for spelling out the difference between the 2 examples to a novice like myself.  The difference is subtle to me, but probably glaringly obvious to real programmers.

Comment: @phan I'm hardly a 'real' programmer myself. The key to this is the order of initialization within the class. If X doesn't have a value yet, and you try to assign Y = X, what is the value of Y?